Can anyone tell me why this is returning as a string? PWSH
I'm trying to make an array of strings in PowerShell script. I don't understand why it keeps returning as one long string and the $var.gettype() returns string.
I tried following all of the array instructions provided by microsoft and it seems that I can only get it to work temporarily in terminal. Also yes i know this might not be incredible code but i'm trying to learn and have gotten about an hour in so be nice pls.
import-module activedirectory
$emaildomains = @('@prismntx.org', '@aidsarms.org', '@phntx.org')

#ask for name
$firstName = Read-Host -Prompt 'First Name: '
$lastName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Last Name: '
    
#generate emails
$fLast = $firstName[0] + $lastName
$firstLast = $firstName + '.' + $lastName
$proxy1 = 'SMTP.' + $firstLast + $emaildomains[0]

write-host $proxy1
write-host $emaildomains.gettype()




Are you sure $emaildomains.GetType() does not actually return [System.String[]] ? (Note the extra square brackets denoting it is a string array)

I get Object[]  Note that write-host sends text directly to the console.

no, it returns "PS C:<filepath>
First Name: : t
Last Name: : s
SMTP.t.s@
System.String
PS C:\Windows\system32>
I've also tried to define the variable using

So i changed the name of the variable and it worked...If i'm running the script, should i first have all the variables cleared before assigning them? I'm not sure why specifically the variable name "emailDomains" is turning it into a string

I get informationrecord.
$emaildomains = '@prismntx.org', '@aidsarms.org', '@phntx.org'
write-host $emaildomains 6>&1 | % gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    InformationRecord                        System.Object

